# Update single column of IndexedDb records using id key

Tags: indexeddb

I want to know how to update IndexedDB records like `(UPDATE TABLE SET column_name= MyNewValue WHERE ID=MyKey)`. I want to update single attribute in a object using the key..

While trying to Update using Cursor, I'm getting this error,

**Uncaught DataError: Failed to execute 'update' on 'IDBCursor': The effective object store of this cursor uses in-line keys and evaluating the key path of the value parameter results in a different value than the cursor's effective key.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for including your error. I can't say with certainty without seeing your object store creation code but I'm very familiar with this type of issue.

What it means is that you're not using auto-incrementing keys, and providing a key yourself. That's very normal. In that case, you use the following [`IDBCursor.update()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBCursor) [signature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBCursor.update).

```
cursor.update(your_updated_entry_object);
```

IDB knows which entry to update because your key is "in-line" on the `your_updated_entry_object` (meaning `your_updated_entry_object` has an attribute that is your key).

It sounds like you may have seen the `IDBStore.put()` method and been confused. That takes on two seperate signatures for so-called "inline keys" (what you have) and "out-of-line" keys (what you get if you let IDB autoincrement the keys for you).

With in-line keys, it's the same signature as `IDBCursor.update()`:

```
store.put(your_updated_entry_object);
```

However with out-of-line keys, it takes on an extra `key` param that tells IDB which object to update (since you're not on a cursor and otherwise has no context for your request):

```
store.put(your-updated_entry_object, your_autoincremented_key);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, `update` method on the cursor is misleading, because it suggests inline primary key can be change as well. There is [a lengthy discussion](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2011JanMar/0327.html) whether to allow changing primary key according to the method.

Actually if primary key were allowed to be changed, it is even more confusing, so [it is not allowed](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#widl-IDBCursor-update-IDBRequest-any-value). The only way is delete and create a new one. It is also same concept for other key-value store as well.

> If the effective object store of this cursor uses in-line keys and evaluating the key path of the value parameter results in a different value than the cursor's effective key, the implementation must throw a DOMException of type DataError.